# .Net Core Swagger not working with Required enum?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger

Using `Swashbuckle` 5.6.3. Controller method looks like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GenerateTokenAsync([FromForm] TokenCredentials tokenCredentials)
```

`TokenCredentials` looks like:

```
    [Required]
    public GrantType? grant_type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

`GrantType` looks like:

```
public enum GrantType
{
    client_credentials = 0
}
```

The enum shows in Swagger and shows as required, but when I hit the execute button, I get the red bounce of death. If I take off the Required, then it executes. I also tried `NotNull`, but that let it through regardless.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` 5.5.0,it's OK. Here is [an official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Result:
[image]

Or you can delete `[FromForm]` in Swashbuckle 5.6.3.

Comment: Doesn't work in 5.5.0 either and you can't remove [FromForm] otherwise it becomes a query parameter.

Comment: I follow the [turtorial of official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.5.0.It can work.

Comment: Hmm... I tried again... had to clear my browser cache. 5.5x does let you send the request, but its broken in a different way. It doesn't enforce the required in the Swagger UI, it lets the service fail the request.